# Block HTTP 'TRACE' in Spring MVC with embedded Jetty server 7.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, embedded-jetty

I'm fairly new to spring security and I'm trying to disable the HTTP 'TRACE'  method on my Spring webapp with Embedded Jetty server 7.5, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried a couple of ways based on questions asked on Stackoverflow, but still no luck.

here are my approaches:
Adding a Separate interceptor as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412463/spring-framework-http-options-returning-all-methods-get-put-post-delete-tr/23412548#23412548):

My Context.xml looked like:

```
<interceptors>

    <interceptor>
        <mapping path="/**"/>
        <beans:bean class="com.mypackage.HTTPMethodsInterceptor" /> 
    </interceptor>
    <interceptor>.... </interceptor>
</interceptors>
```

My Interceptor class:

```
public class HTTPMethodsInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    if (!request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")
            && !request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("GET")
            && !request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("PUT")
            && !request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("DELETE")) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN,
                "Unauthorized Request");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

This doesn't work even on my local. I tried debugging and putting a breakpoint interceptor class, but the breakpoint is not hit anytime.

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or is there any correct way to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `web.xml`?

Comment: @PeterRader Yes I do have a web.xml